# Video Uploading and viewing in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing a Social Networking site..I am done with basic functionality.Now I want my users to upload video and let them view..at the same time The can even delete or edit it as well.

I cam across few implementation practices such as HTML5,FlowPlayer,YouTube Data API.
Among st them I like Youtube Data API the most.  but i am having few Questions that i want to share..

Does video uploaded by user is searchable...if yes then i will have problem of privacy.

Or Can anybody specify me What's the best way to achive this task...?

Comment: Video added by Youtube API will be searchable, yes. Best way is to use Youtube's API code for C#. Do you want its code?

Comment: is it possible to make it hidden or What if i want to have privacy setting that no one other than him self would be able to view his video at all.
defiantly i would like to have a look at the code whether i will use it or not but i will learn something new. 
and again Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, you can set Video settings from `Broadcast and Sharing Options` when you are finished with uploading video, and then EDIT the video. Or you can select UNLIST from privacy settings on upload screen.

Comment: Please make sure you're aware of the issue raised in this blog post: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html

Comment: I have gone through your post link...I think i would like to have a single Account for my website and i will manage videos of users from the same since it's possible that any user may not be having youtube account and in that case he may not be able to upload the same..

I have search and find link for using Youtube API but is there any link that gives pdf version which has to be in details depth documentation.

Some code example so that i can understand how can i design my youtube framework